# JBPM Workflow patch generation

Tags: workflow, jbpm

I have been using JBPM workflow in my project and I have a small question regarding generating the database patches or SQL statements to apply JBPM workflow modifications.

Currently JBPM workflow provides a way to refresh the JBPM tables in schema with the deployment of the latest process definitions. However what if my system is already live with process definition deployed with state X and now I have modified the process definition file to accommodate change X2. I still need to be able to deploy the delta changes without disrupting the instances of old saved data.

Is it possible to generate only "delta" database scripts for the JBPM process definition modification? And what are other good tools which can be used to modify process definitions more intuitively?

To reiterate on my problem, JBPM deploy cleans the JBPM tables of old instances maintained there and then redeploys the latest files; how do I generate the delta without deleting old data? Are there any user friendly tools for that?

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to have understood correctly your issue. JBpm doesn't clean tables for old process instances when you deploy a new process definition.

When you deploy a new process definition with the same name of an existing one, you get new version of that process definition.

Existing process instances continue running with the process definition version they was started with, while new process instances take the latest version unless you specify the precise version to be used.

In theory, process definition can also be modified for running process instances using the API. In doing so, you must pay attention to make these changes compatible with the flowing of these instances.